# Is it possible to use OpenGL ES 3.0 for Android Instant Apps?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to use OpenGL ES 3.0 for Android Instant Apps, but `GL_VERSION` returns `OpenGL ES 2.0 Instant Apps`, which means it only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 (and 2.0 Ext).

Is there any way to use OpenGL ES 3.0?
I've tried `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />` but it didn't work.
Or anyone know any official documents about Android Instant Apps runtime environments?

If I built my app as normal apk with `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />`, `GL_VERSION` returns `OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r12p1-03dev0.228ab63cced004f840e7dd47b762a1d0` as I expected.

I'm testing this with Samsung Galaxy S7 edge (Android 7.0).

Comment: On Android 8.1.0 device GL_VERSION returns OpenGL ES 3.2. Have you tried on O+ devices? On pre-O I also get “OpenGL ES 2.0 Instant Apps”.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! So it seems like Android 8.1.0 now supports OpenGL ES 3.x. I'll try on Android 8.1.0 devices if it runs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132952558, quoting:

> OpenGL ES 1.0 is only partially supported for Instant Apps, we do not
>   recommend you to use this.
>
> OpenGL ES 2.0 is fully supported for Instant Apps.
>
> Additionally, OpenGL ES 3.0 is not supported on pre-O Instant Apps.
>
> This was previously documented somewhere, but not anymore, so we’re
>   working on getting these details back in.